How can i prove the Darboux equation for a surface embedded into a 3D Riemannian Manifold?
I'm studying the generalizzation of the Darboux equation into immersions in Riemannian 3D space instead of 3D Euclidean space.
Basically, in the Euclidean case, given a surface $\Sigma$ with metric
$$ds^2 = Edu^2 + 2F dudv + G dv^2 $$
one can study the local embedding condition with $x = x(u,v)$ $y = y(u,v)$ $z = z(u,v)$ where $u,v \in U \subset R^2$  with $U$ a neighbourhood of $(u,v) =(0,0)$.
$$ dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 = Edu^2 + 2F dudv + G dv^2$$
One can get the Darboux equation taking between one (i use $z$) of the unknow functions $(x,y,z)$ and bring it to the other side
$$dx^2 + dy^2 = ds^2 - dz^2$$
Using the fact that
$$dz = z_u du + z_v dv$$ the Darboux condition becomes
$$dx^2 + dy^2 = (E - (z_u)^2)du^2 + 2(F - (z_u)(z_v))dudv + (G - (z_v)^2)dv^2$$
the Darboux equation follows after computing the gaussian curvature both sides in the Darboux condition. Since on the RHS we have a plane, the gaussian curvature of the right member is $K' = 0$. While the curvature of the LHS is
$$\Delta_{22}z -K(1- \Delta_1z) $$
$K$ is the curvature of the known surface $\Sigma$. This proof is explained on Bianchi Vol.1 as i know so far. For the riemannian case the condition is similar except for the fact that we don't have necessary a zero curvature on the RHS, so the condition
$d\bar{s}^2 = ds^2 - d\phi^2$ provides
$$\bar{K} = \frac{1}{1-\Delta_1\phi}(K - \frac{\Delta_{22}\phi}{1-\Delta_1\phi}) $$
How can i get this identity? I can't find it in any book, only this paper use it and gives a reference which i cannot find: https://camath.fudan.edu.cn/camb/ch/reader/create_pdf.aspx?file_no=20B209&year_id=1999&quarter_id=2&falg=1
$\textbf{EDIT: 11/07/2024}:$ I just found a simpler way to get the generalized Darboux equation (the 2.1 expression of https://camath.fudan.edu.cn/camb/ch/reader/create_pdf.aspx?file_no=20B209&year_id=1999&quarter_id=2&falg=1).
to get the generalized Darboux equation we need this generic result:
$*$ the curvature of a generic surface is given by the Brioschi Formula https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrioschiFormula.html :
$$K = \frac{M_1 - M_2}{(EG-F^2)^2}$$
This means that if we are studying the local embedding
$$d\bar{s}^2 = ds^2 - d\phi^2 $$ we can express the known curvature $\bar{k}$ of $d\bar{s}^2$ in this way
$$\tilde{K} = \frac{\tilde{M}_1 - \tilde{M}_2}{(\tilde{E}\tilde{G}-\tilde{F}^2)^2}$$ where every bar term is constructed by the substitution $E \rightarrow (E - (\phi_u)^2)$ ; $G \rightarrow (G - (\phi_v)^2)$; $F \rightarrow (F - (\phi_u)(\phi_v))$.
Please note that
$$(\bar{E}\bar{G}-\bar{F}^2)^2 = (EG -F)^2(1 - \Delta_1\phi)^2$$
So the Brioschi Formula for the $d\bar{s}^2$ metric becomes
$$\bar{K}(1 - \Delta_1\phi)^2 = \frac{\bar{M}_1 - \bar{M}_2}{(EG - F^2)^2}$$
We need to split $\bar{M}_1 - \bar{M}_2$ in the following way
$$ \bar{M}_1 - \bar{M}_2 = A(\phi_{,i} ; \phi_{,ij}) (M_1 - M_2) + B(\phi_{,i} ; \phi_{,ij})$$
$A(\phi_{,i} ; \phi_{,ij})$ and $B(\phi_{,i} ; \phi_{,ij})$ are expressions that must be found. they are independent from $\bar{K}$ and they depend on the first and second derivative of $\phi$. The curvature expression become
$$\bar{K}(1 - \Delta_1\phi)^2 = \frac{A(M_1 - M_2)}{(EG - F^2)^2} + \frac{B}{(EG - F^2)^2}$$
$$\bar{K}(1 - \Delta_1\phi)^2 = A \cdot K + \frac{B}{(EG - F^2)^2} $$
If $\bar{K} = 0$ we have that $K = \frac{\Delta_{22}\phi}{1-\Delta_1\phi}$. Hence
$$ \frac{B}{A (EG-F^2)^2} = -\frac{\Delta_{22}\phi}{1-\Delta_1\phi}$$
So $ A = \rho \cdot (1-\Delta_1\phi)$ and $B = -\rho \cdot (EG-F^2)^2 \cdot \Delta_{22}\phi$, where $\rho$ is a function of $(u,v)$ that must be computed. Since $A$ and $B$ are independent from $\bar{K}$ we have that this is always true so for any $\rho$
$$\bar{K} = \frac{\rho}{1-\Delta_1\phi}(K - \frac{\Delta_{22}\phi}{1-\Delta_1\phi}) $$
Using Wolfram, the relation $\bar{M}_1 - \bar{M}_2 = \rho \cdot (1-\Delta_1\phi) (M_1 - M_2) -\rho \cdot \Delta_{22}\phi(EG-F^2)^2$ is true only when $\rho =1$.

Since this equation has not been used much, it's not in most references. It's also not hard to derive yourself. If you write a paper using it, you could put a derivation of it in an appendix.

Could you give me an hint? Because i can"t figure out how to get the right member. I mean $\tilde{K}(1-\Delta_1\phi)= ...$

Sorry but my comment is incorrect. The paper you cite makes a strong assumption on the Riemannian $3$-manifold (equation (2.6)). Your calculation above also makes a similar assumption. Basically, you have to assume that the $3$-manifold contains a surface with constant curvature in order to derive a Darboux equation that is equivalent to the isometric embedding equation.

the problem studied by Darboux is a local embedding. In the Euclidean case only locally the metric on the right side is defined and has zero curvature. The second case is similar but you have a non zero curvature, i have to use this equation because i'm studying trapped 2D surface in the FLRW metric. The problem is that behind this equation there are a lot of computation to do because the metric is taken in a generic form and not a specific one. The purpose is to find, solving that equation, all the surfaces equivalent to a given surface embedded in the 3D Rimannian manifold.

I'm talking about the (2.1) of the article. I need the proof of it, that equation is the generalizzation of the Darboux eq.

I do not know what the easiest way to do the calculation for (2.1) in the paper. It might be just grinding it all out in local coordinates using $E, F, G, \widetilde{E}, \widetilde{F}, \widetilde{G}$ and their partial derivatives. Or using Christoffel symbols.
Another possible way that still involves some messy calculations is using moving frames. I haven't done the full calculations, but I can set it all up for you.
$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$
On an open domain $\Omega\subset\R^2$, let $g$ be a Riemannian metric and
$(\omega^1, \omega^2)$ be an orthonormal coframe of $1$-forms for $g$, i.e.,
$$ g = (\omega^1)^2 + (\omega^2)^2. $$
Let $\omega^1_2= -\omega^2_1$ be the connection $1$-form, i.e., the unique $1$-form satisfying
\begin{align*}
  d\omega^1 + \omega^1_2\wedge\omega^2 &= 0\\
  d\omega^2 + \omega^2_1\wedge\omega^1 &= 0.
\end{align*}
Recall that
\begin{align*}
  d\omega^1_2 &= K_g\omega^1\wedge\omega^2,
\end{align*}
where $K_g$ is the Gauss curvature of $g$.
Let $\phi$ a smooth scalar function such that $d\phi \ne 0$. Let
$$
  d\phi = \phi_1\omega^1 + \phi_2\omega^2.
$$
Observe that
$$ g(d\phi,d\phi) = (\phi_1)^2+(\phi_2)^2. $$
Consider the Riemannian metric
$$ h = g + (d\phi)^2. $$
We want to find the Gauss curvature $K_h$ of $h$. First, note that
\begin{align*}
  h &= g + d\phi^2\\
    &= (\omega^1)^2 + (\omega^2)^1 + (\phi_1\omega^1 + \phi_2\omega^2)^2\\
    &= \frac{(1+g(d\phi,d\phi))(\phi_1\omega^1+\phi_2\omega^2)^2 + (-\phi_2\omega^1+\phi_1\omega^2)^2}{g(d\phi,d\phi)}\\
    &= (\theta^1)^2 + (\theta^2)^2,
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
  \theta^1 &= \left(\frac{1+g(d\phi,d\phi)}{g(d\phi,d\phi)}\right)^{1/2}(\phi_1\omega^1+\phi_2\omega^2)\\
  \theta^2 &= \frac{1}{(g(d\phi,d\phi))^{1/2}}(-\phi_2\omega^1+\phi_1\omega^2).
\end{align*}
Therefore, $(\theta^1,\theta^2)$ is an orthonormal coframe for $h$. Let $\theta^1_2 = -\theta^2_1$ be the connection $1$-form.
Now note that the Hessian of $\phi$ with respect to the orthonormal coframe is the symmetric matrix
$$  \begin{bmatrix} \phi_{11} & \phi_{12} \\ \phi_{21} & \phi_{22} \end{bmatrix}, $$
where
$$ d\phi_i - \phi_k\omega^k_i = \phi_{ij}\omega^j. $$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
  d(g(d\phi,d\phi)) &= d((\phi_1)^2 + (\phi_2)^2)\\
                    &= 2(\phi_1\,d\phi_1 + \phi_2\,d\phi_2)\\
                    &= 2(\phi_1(\phi_2\omega^2_1 + \phi_{1j}\omega^j)
                      + \phi_2(\phi_1\omega^1_2 + \phi_{2j}\omega^j))\\
                    &= 2(\phi_1\phi_{1j}+\phi_2\phi_{2j})\omega^j.
\end{align*}
You can now use all of this to find the formula for the connection $1$-form $\theta^1_2$ in terms of $\omega^1, \omega^2, \omega^1_2, \phi_1,\phi_2, $ and the Hessian of $\phi$. You then get the formula for the Gauss curvature of $h$ by calculating $d\theta^1_2$.
All I can say is that when I was learning differential geometry, I did a lot of calculations like this. Sometimes you find a better way, but usually you don't figure out how until after you have done the long and messy way first.
